# XSLT 1.0 group values using two criterias

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this XML:

```
<test>                               
   <itemGroup>        
    <item>
        <date>20151020</date>
        <time>1201</time>
        <amount>1.000</amount>
    </item>
    <item>
        <date>20151020</date>
        <time>1202</time>
        <amount>1.000</amount>
    </item>
    <item>
        <date>20151020</date>
        <time>1203</time>
        <amount>1.000</amount>
    </item>
    <item>
        <date>20151020</date>
        <time>1204</time>
        <amount>1.000</amount>
    </item>
    <item>
        <date>20151020</date>
        <time>1205</time>
        <amount>1.000</amount>
    </item>

    <item>
        <date>20151021</date>
        <time>1301</time>
        <amount>1.000</amount>
    </item>
    <item>
        <date>20151021</date>
        <time>1302</time>
        <amount>1.000</amount>
    </item>
    <item>
        <date>20151021</date>
        <time>1303</time>
        <amount>1.000</amount>
    </item>
    <item>
        <date>20151021</date>
        <time>1304</time>
        <amount>1.000</amount>
    </item>
    <item>
        <date>20151021</date>
        <time>1305</time>
        <amount>1.000</amount>
    </item>

</itemGroup>
<itemGroup>        
    <item>                        
        <date>20151022</date>
        <time>1047</time>
        <amount>1.000</amount>
    </item>
    <item>
        <date>20151022</date>
        <time>1147</time>
        <amount>1.000</amount>
    </item>                
    <item>
        <date>20151022</date>
        <time>1247</time>
        <amount>1.000</amount>
    </item>                    
</itemGroup>
<itemGroup>      
    <item>
        <date>20151020</date>
        <time>2211</time>
        <amount>1.000</amount>
    </item>
    <item>
        <date>20151020</date>
        <time>2222</time>
        <amount>1.000</amount>
    </item>                   
</itemGroup>                
</test>
```

And the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

<xsl:template match="test">
    <Main>          
        <xsl:apply-templates select="itemGroup"/>           
    </Main>     
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="itemGroup">
    <xsl:comment>** item Group #<xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:comment>

    <xsl:variable name="Max_Size">3</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:comment>item count : <xsl:value-of select="count(item)"/></xsl:comment>
    <xsl:comment> </xsl:comment>

    <xsl:for-each select="item[ position() mod $Max_Size = 1 or (not(date=preceding-sibling::item/date) and not(position() mod $Max_Size = 1)) ]">
        <xsl:comment>** Header <xsl:value-of select="position()"/> </xsl:comment>

        <segment name="Header">
            <xsl:attribute name="nb"><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:attribute>
            <element name="date"><xsl:value-of select="date"/></element>
            <element name="sum"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(../item/amount), '0')"/></element><!--sum of all amount of this group-->                
        </segment>

        <xsl:for-each select=".|following-sibling::item[position() &lt; $Max_Size and date=preceding-sibling::item/date]">              
            <segment name="item">                   
                <element name="time"><xsl:value-of select="time"/></element>
            </segment>              
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
<Main>
<!--** item Group #1-->
<!--item count : 10-->
<!---->
<!--** Header 1-->
<segment name="Header" nb="1">
    <element name="date">20151020</element>
    <element name="sum">10</element>
</segment>
<segment name="item">
    <element name="time">1201</element>
</segment>
<segment name="item">
    <element name="time">1202</element>
</segment>
<segment name="item">
    <element name="time">1203</element>
</segment>
<!--** Header 2-->
<segment name="Header" nb="2">
    <element name="date">20151020</element>
    <element name="sum">10</element>
</segment>
<segment name="item">
    <element name="time">1204</element>
</segment>
<segment name="item">
    <element name="time">1205</element>
</segment>
<!--** Header 3-->
<segment name="Header" nb="3">
    <element name="date">20151021</element>
    <element name="sum">10</element>
</segment>
<segment name="item">
    <element name="time">1301</element>
</segment>
<segment name="item">
    <element name="time">1302</element>
</segment>
<segment name="item">
    <element name="time">1303</element>
</segment>
<!--** Header 4-->
<segment name="Header" nb="4">
    <element name="date">20151021</element>
    <element name="sum">10</element>
</segment>
<segment name="item">
    <element name="time">1302</element>
</segment>
<segment name="item">
    <element name="time">1303</element>
</segment>
<segment name="item">
    <element name="time">1304</element>
</segment>
<!--** Header 5-->
<segment name="Header" nb="5">
    <element name="date">20151021</element>
    <element name="sum">10</element>
</segment>
<segment name="item">
    <element name="time">1305</element>
</segment>
<!--** item Group #2-->
<!--item count : 3-->
<!---->
<!--** Header 1-->
<segment name="Header" nb="1">
    <element name="date">20151022</element>
    <element name="sum">3</element>
</segment>
<segment name="item">
    <element name="time">1047</element>
</segment>
<segment name="item">
    <element name="time">1147</element>
</segment>
<segment name="item">
    <element name="time">1247</element>
</segment>
<!--** item Group #3-->
<!--item count : 2-->
<!---->
<!--** Header 1-->
<segment name="Header" nb="1">
    <element name="date">20151020</element>
    <element name="sum">2</element>
</segment>
<segment name="item">
    <element name="time">2211</element>
</segment>
<segment name="item">
    <element name="time">2222</element>
</segment>
</Main>
```

What I want to achieve is to group the values according to theses criterias.

1- All the item for a same date.
2- The group size must not exceed "Max_Size" (3), a new group should be started instead.

I was able to achieve those two criterias separately it's when trying to have them together that it stopped working.

Optional bonus question : Having the   total the amount from the current group only.

I have to use 1.0

Here is the output I am expecting :

```
<Main>
<!--** item Group #1-->
<!--item count : 10-->
<!---->
<!--** Header 1-->
<segment name="Header" nb="1">
    <element name="date">20151020</element>
    <element name="sum">3</element>
</segment>
<segment name="item">
    <element name="time">1201</element>
</segment>
<segment name="item">
    <element name="time">1202</element>
</segment>
<segment name="item">
    <element name="time">1203</element>
</segment>
<!--** Header 2-->
<segment name="Header" nb="2">
    <element name="date">20151020</element>
    <element name="sum">3</element>
</segment>
<segment name="item">
    <element name="time">1204</element>
</segment>
<segment name="item">
    <element name="time">1205</element>
</segment>
<!--** Header 3-->
<segment name="Header" nb="3">
    <element name="date">20151021</element>
    <element name="sum">3</element>
</segment>
<segment name="item">
    <element name="time">1301</element>
</segment>
<segment name="item">
    <element name="time">1302</element>
</segment>
<segment name="item">
    <element name="time">1303</element>
</segment>
<!--** Header 4-->
<segment name="Header" nb="4">
    <element name="date">20151021</element>
    <element name="sum">2</element>
</segment>    
<segment name="item">
    <element name="time">1304</element>
</segment>
<segment name="item">
    <element name="time">1305</element>
</segment>    
<!--** item Group #2-->
<!--item count : 3-->
<!---->
<!--** Header 1-->
<segment name="Header" nb="1">
    <element name="date">20151022</element>
    <element name="sum">3</element>
</segment>
<segment name="item">
    <element name="time">1047</element>
</segment>
<segment name="item">
    <element name="time">1147</element>
</segment>
<segment name="item">
    <element name="time">1247</element>
</segment>
<!--** item Group #3-->
<!--item count : 2-->
<!---->
<!--** Header 1-->
<segment name="Header" nb="1">
    <element name="date">20151020</element>
    <element name="sum">2</element>
</segment>
<segment name="item">
    <element name="time">2211</element>
</segment>
<segment name="item">
    <element name="time">2222</element>
</segment>
</Main>
```

Comment: "*1- All the item for a same date.*" That's not what your output shows. You have 2 groups (3+2 items) for date 20151020 in the beginning, and another group for the same date (with 2 items) at the end.

Comment: yes sorry,  each itemGroup (from original xml)   is a different item,  so they can  and will have overlapping date.    itemGroup should all be treated separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is partially a grouping question, and in XSLT 1.0 you can use the technique called [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)

You are grouping `item` elements by date, within a given `itemGroup`, so you would define a key like so

```
<xsl:key name="items" match="item" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', date)" />
```

To get the distinct `item` elements for each date, normally you would do this

```
<xsl:for-each select="item[count(. | key('items', concat(generate-id(..), '|', date))[1]) = 1]">
```

But you have the added complexity of wanting to select groups of 3. You can this with this fearsome expression:

```
<xsl:for-each 
     select="item[count(. | key('items', concat(generate-id(..), '|', date))[position() mod $Max_Size = 1]) 
                  = ceiling(count(key('items', concat(generate-id(..), '|', date))) div $Max_Size)]">
```

Then the items in the group would be defined like so:

```
<xsl:variable name="group" select=".|following-sibling::item[position() &lt; $Max_Size and date = current()/date]" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

<xsl:key name="items" match="item" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', date)" />

<xsl:template match="test">
    <Main>   
        <xsl:apply-templates select="itemGroup"/>           
    </Main>     
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="itemGroup">
    <xsl:comment>** item Group #<xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:comment>

    <xsl:variable name="Max_Size">3</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:comment>item count : <xsl:value-of select="count(item)"/></xsl:comment>
    <xsl:comment> </xsl:comment>
    <xsl:for-each select="item[count(. | key('items', concat(generate-id(..), '|', date))[position() mod $Max_Size = 1]) = ceiling(count(key('items', concat(generate-id(..), '|', date))) div $Max_Size)]">
        <xsl:comment>** Header <xsl:value-of select="position()"/> </xsl:comment>

        <xsl:variable name="group" select=".|following-sibling::item[position() &lt; $Max_Size and date = current()/date]" />
        <segment name="Header">
            <xsl:attribute name="nb"><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:attribute>
            <element name="date"><xsl:value-of select="date"/></element>
            <element name="sum"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum($group/amount), '0')"/></element><!--sum of all amount of this group-->                
        </segment>

        <xsl:for-each select="$group">              
            <segment name="item">                   
                <element name="time"><xsl:value-of select="time"/></element>
            </segment>              
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Isn't this assuming items are sorted within each group?

Comment: i confirm data is expected to aleady be sorted within each group.   I'm still interested in knowing how unsorted item could be parsed,  with the sort() function i guess ?

Comment: @JimCusler The problem with handling unsorted items is not "parsing". Sub-grouping them into groups of 3 is more difficult, since the members of the group are not necessarily adjacent siblings. One way you could handle this is by dividing the transformation into 2 passes, so that the sub-grouping in the 2nd pass does deal with contiguous groups.